# Filtering in Join with date sequence table

Tags: mysql

Edit:  see 3rd SQL example below with subquery. It produces desired result: filtering on class.level =  with no date gaps.  Doesn't seem like a very efficient query, though.

I'm using a pre-filled date sequence table and LEFT JOINing it to an events table to "fill-in the gaps" between event dates. The events table has relation to a class table on events.class_id = classs.id to pull in class info.

In order to filter on a class col and preserve the date sequence, I have to put class col condition in the events, classes join below.
This works but the event records are still returned with null for class name. Yellow highlight good, red highlight not. Want to the same result but without event records in red

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `date_sequence` (
   date_ date NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `events` (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  class_id mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  start_dt datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  end_dt datetime DEFAULT NULL,
) 

CREATE TABLE `classes` (
  id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  name varchar(48) NOT NULL,
  level tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
) 




// regular select, no filter
SELECT
c.name,
e.id AS event_id,
e.class_id AS class_id,
e.start_dt,
ds.date_ AS `date`,
FROM date_sequence ds 
LEFT JOIN events e ON DATE(e.start_dt) = ds.date_ 
LEFT JOIN classes c ON e.class_id =c.id
WHERE  ds.date_ >= '2018-04-01' AND  ds.date_ < '2018-05-01'
ORDER BY ds.date_, e.start_dt



// with filter on class.level = 2  has gaps
SELECT
c.name,
e.id AS event_id,
e.class_id AS class_id,
e.start_dt,
ds.date_ AS `date`,
FROM date_sequence ds 
LEFT JOIN events e ON DATE(e.start_dt) = ds.date_ 
LEFT JOIN classes c ON e.class_id =c.id AND c.level = 2
WHERE  ds.date_ >= '2018-04-01' AND  ds.date_ < '2018-05-01'
ORDER BY ds.date_, e.start_dt




// No gaps
SELECT
B.name,
B.level,
B.id AS event_id,
B.class_id AS class_id,
B.start_dt,
ds.date_ AS `date`,
FROM date_sequence ds 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT events.*, c.name, c.level
 FROM events 
 LEFT JOIN classes c ON events.class_id = c.id
 WHERE c.level=1
) 
AS B ON  ds.date_ = DATE(B.start_dt)
WHERE  ds.date_ >= '2018-06-01' AND ds.date_ < '2018-07-01'
ORDER BY ds.date_, B.start_dt
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `HAVING` condition to your query and create condition basing on existing or not existing class id. First add this part into your select:
`SELECT c.name, c.id as cid, e.id AS event_id,`

see, I added `c.id as cid` to be able to use it in `HAVING`

and then just after `WHERE` statement:

`WHERE  ds.date_ >= '2018-04-01' AND  ds.date_ < '2018-05-01' HAVING ((cid IS NULL AND event_id IS NULL) or cid IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY ds.date_, e.start_dt`

so the entire SQL query looks like this:

`SELECT c.name, c.id as cid, e.id AS event_id, e.class_id AS class_id, e.start_dt, ds.date_ AS`date`FROM date_sequence ds LEFT JOIN events e ON DATE(e.start_dt) = ds.date_ LEFT JOIN classes c ON e.class_id =c.id AND c.level = 2 WHERE  ds.date_ >= '2018-04-01' AND  ds.date_ < '2018-05-01' HAVING ((cid IS NULL AND event_id IS NULL) or cid IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY ds.date_, e.start_dt`

Comment: But then I get gaps in the date sequence

Comment: No, if you'll filter using HAVING on cid you won't get gaps. If you'd filtered through class_id (taken from event table) then yes, you are right. Did you test my query? I just run it and it returns desired result.

Comment: Yes, I tested it, copy and paste. I'm filtering on class.level in the JOIN

Comment: The date range filter is on the date_sequence table so may I should do some sort of sub query